Quadruples such that the greatest prime divisor of $n^2 + 1$ is equal
An old problem in KöMaL magazine asked the following charming problem.

(KöMaL A. 643) For every positive integer $n$, let $P(n)$ be the greatest prime divisor of $n^2+1$. Show that there are infinitely many quadruples $(a,b,c,d)$ of positive integers that satisfy $a<b<c<d$ and $P(a)=P(b)=P(c)=P(d)$.

It seems an interesting problem but I failed to find a solution to it.
My questions are

Could you please provide a solution to this problem?
Is there some research level material for this problem, i.e. could $P(n)$ takes some infinite set of value more often?


The sequence https://oeis.org/A014442 seems to be relevant, although none of the references there are immediately helpful.

@MichaelLugo  Well, knowing that each prime of the form $p=4k+1$  occurs (exactly) twice in the first $p$ integers  is useful, and that is proven there.  The list seems to be too short to see any other patterns....

Oh, I didn't read carefully.  It lists the first $1000$ values.  Worth searching to see which primes show up often, and where.

FYI, using an Approach0 search, there are the AoPS threads Number theory (see Post #$5$) and greatest prime divisor, with this linking to Greatest prime divisor of n^2+1.

@JohnOmielan Thanks a lot for your indication. I feel sorry about not sufficiently searching for it.

You're welcome. Don't worry about not sufficiently searching for it. The site's built-in search, or even a general search engine like Google or Bing, often don't work very well with searching math questions, in particular math expressions. This is why I often use Approach0 instead. One other thing to consider is that, if you think you have a correct solution, such as one based on solutions in my linked AoPS threads, please consider posting your own answer here.
